# Parsing a word document into an Oracle Apex form page

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Currently have a custom Applicant Tracking System/Client Relationship Management system built in Apex 5.1, part of the ATS portion allows the recruiter to type in candidate data into system and attach a resume.

The request that I currently have right now is that they don't like typing since it takes too long, so they want a way that you can just upload and parse the contents of the resume to fill in the form fields for them.

Is there a way in Apex 5.1 that allows for parsing a word document and placing the contact and skills information into the form or even directly into a table bypassing the form completely?

Comment: Relevant: https://xkcd.com/1425/

Answer (score 0):

No replies yet, so - let me try (won't help much, I'm afraid).

If you open a Word document in any text editor, you'll see that it looks like a *binary* file. For testing purposes, I created a new MS Word 2010 (docx) document and put a single word in there: "Littlefoot". Then I opened it with Notepad++ and searched for "Littlefoot" - nothing was found, as if Word "encrypted" file contents.

Therefore, I believe that this is not a single task - not by the mean of "I'll use UTL_FILE and find some keywords and extract what's behind them and put those values into my Oracle table".

I *think* I remember that someone tried to parse Word files as if they were XML but ... huh, got nothing or something unexpected, can't remember any more.

My next idea was to use a scanner and OCR (optical character recognition) software whose output would be a TXT file - if you manage to do that, then it's a relatively simple task to write some UTL_FILE code against it and collect information you need.

Yet another option is to create an application which would be used by candidates - they'd enter values you're interested in and upload their resume (you'd put it into a BLOB data type column), but that might be somewhat tricky if your network isn't exposed to the Internet so candidates would have to enter your premises in order to fill that information.

Or, create a "dummy" application (used by candidates again) which would fill required information; application would generate a 2D barcode that would contain those info, and you'd just read it with a barcode scanner.

As I said, not very useful, but I've got plenty ideas. I'm sure other people have a lot more of them.

Comment: Word .docx files are a zipped collection of XML files. Plenty of tools exist to extract content from them e.g. [Tika](http://tika.apache.org). I'm not aware of any in PL/SQL though.

Comment: @chrisis: Aha, so I remembered well (kind of) that it has something to do with XML. Right, I found *myself* in document.xml, once I opened the ZIP. Thank you!

Comment: Oracle's XMLDB libraries and the xmltype data type would be able to shred docx into useful data.  Not for the faint of heart, though.